# NPOI does not recognized end of file

Tags: c#, npoi

I am using NPOI library in order to read .xls and .xlsx files.

However I have this issue, the method GetRow() does not return null even when the row is empty.

Here is the code

```
int idx_row = 1;
IRow currentRow = sheet.GetRow(idx_row);
while (currentRow != null)
{
    JObject jsonData = new JObject();
    jsonData["a"] = sheet.GetRow(idx_row).GetCell(0).StringCellValue.Replace(" ", "");
    // other similar code
    jsonPlateData.Add(jsonData);
    idx_row++;
    currentRow = sheet.GetRow(idx_row);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `sheet.LastRowNum`, it's possible that the row seems empty but excel considers it as filled. If so, open the excel file and delete the rows that are "empty".

Comment: Sorry again, this file is an output from another application. How can I remove those lines? Otherwise there is a method to discover when the lines with content are ended?

Comment: You can try parsing the contents of the cell that shouldn't be empty and exit the while loop when there is no data.

Comment: The problem is that if I try to access that cell I get an error

Comment: Well it's not the most suitable solution, but you can know when to stop when that error pops up. Try catching that particular exception in a catch block, inside your while. I haven't used NPOI for a while, I can't think for another solution, sorry D:

Comment: I was thinking the same. Not really clean as solution.. anyway thank you again for you help